# Find missing element SQL

Tags: sql, matrix

I have a couple of tables of a database where one defines a set of matrices and the other the data in the matrices

Matrices

```
Id  Name
1   M1
2   M2
3   M3
4   M4
```

MatrixElements

```
Matrix_Id   ElementKey  Value
1           1           234
1           2           234
1           3           4432
2           1           234
2           2           13
2           3           123
3           1           34
3           3           345
4           1           234
4           2           11
4           3           344
```

So the `Matrix_Id` column is a foreign key back to the `Id` of the `Matrices` table. The `ElementKey` reprents an ij pair. The matrices are sparse, so there may or may not be an element with a specific key. However, if one matrix has a particular `ElementKey`, then the `ElementKey` with that ID must be defined in ALL matrices.

Is there some SQL that I can run that will find `Matrix_Id` and `ElementKey` combinations for any offending entries, i.e. one that is not defined for all matrices? So for the example above, `ElementKey` = 2 is defined for Matrix 1, 2 and 4 but not 3, so I would expect `[Matrix = 3, ElementKey = 2]` back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the missing elements and the matrices they are in:

```
select m.id, me.element_key
from matrices m cross join
     (select distinct element_key from matrix_elements me) e left join
     matrix_elements me
     on me.matrix_id = m.id and me.element_key = e.element_key
where me.matrix_id is null;
```

The `cross join` generates all combinations of matrices with known element keys.  The `left join` and `where` then find the ones that are missing.

Answer (score 0):

First we make a list of all live elements, then cross join to all active matrices. With this list, we left join the active elements and use a case to determine if they exist.

I've used ANSI, but a CTE would be better if SQL server or Oracle.

```
select c.id, c.ElementKey, case when b.MatrixID is null then 0 else 1 end as InPlace
from
  (
  select id, a.ElementKey
  from Matrices
  cross join
    (
    select distinct ElementKey
    from MatrixElements
    ) a
  ) c
left join Matrices b
on b.Matrix_id = c.id
and b.ElementKey = c.ElementKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the responses I have had. I haven't been able to implement it effectively because I am using Entity Framework and it is hard to translate the code given to a query statement that will give me back the results. I did take inspiration from the samples given and this is what I came up with.

```
public class Matrix
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<MatrixElement> Data { get; set; }
}

public class MatrixElement
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OdPairKey { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
}

public class EngineDataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<Matrix> MatrixFiles { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MatrixElement> MatrixData { get; set; }
}

public class SqliteRepository
{
    private readonly EngineDataContext _dataContext;

    public SqliteRepository(EngineDataContext dataContext)
    {
        _dataContext = dataContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Tuple<Matrix, int>> FindMissingODPairs(IEnumerable<Matrix> matrices)
    {
        IEnumerable<Matrix> matricesWithData =
            matrices.Select(m => _dataContext.MatrixFiles
            .Include("Data").First(mf => mf.Id == m.Id));

        // Do the cross join on matrices and OD pairs
        IEnumerable<dynamic> combinations =
            from m in matrices
            from od in matricesWithData.SelectMany(mat => mat.Data.Select(md => md.OdPairKey)).Distinct()
            select new { M = m.Id, O = od };

        // Find all the used matrix / OD pair combinations
        IEnumerable<dynamic> used =
            from m in matricesWithData
            from od in m.Data
            select new { M = m.Id, O = od.OdPairKey };

        // Find the missing combinations with a simple "Except" query
        return combinations
            .Except(used)
            .Select(c => new Tuple<Matrix, int>(matrices.First(m => m.Id == c.M), c.O));
    }
}
```